# Informações de Cidade e CEP se comportando estranho. PHP Mailer, Html

Tags: html, phpmailer, cep

Olá comunidade tudo bem?

Estou com um problema muito estranho.
Tenho um FORM html, e um programa php mailer que envia as informações mapeadas.
Porém apenas 2 campos se comportam de forma muito estranho, os campos Cidade e CEP.

Assim é como eu recebo:

[image: Campos CEP e Cidade recebidos no e-mail]

Abaixo vou deixar apenas estrutura dos campos e o php mailer.

```
            <div id="cadastro-basico">
                <label for="nome-empresa">Nome da Empresa</label>
                <input type="text" id="nome-empresa" class="input-padrao" required name="nomeempresa">

                <label for="cnpj-empresa">CNPJ da Empresa</label>
                <input type="text" id="cnpj-empresa" class="input-padrao" required name="cnpjempresa">

                <label for="pessoa-contato">Pessoa de contato</label>
                <input type="text" id="pessoa-contato" class="input-padrao" required name="pessoacontato">

                <label for="setor-contato">Setor onde o Contato atua dentro da empresa</label>
                <input type="text" id="setor-contato" class="input-padrao" required name="setorcontato">

                <label for="estado">Estado</label>
                <input type="text" id="estado" class="input-padrao" required placeholder="SP, RJ, MG, etc..  " name="estado">

                <label for="cidade">Cidade</label>
                <input type="text" id="cidade" class="input-padrao" required placeholder="São Paulo, Belo Horizonte, Salvador, etc.." name="cidade">

                <label for="cep">CEP</label>
                <input type="text" id="cep" class="input-padrao" required placeholder="XXXXX-XXX" name="cep" pattern="[0-9]*">

                <label for="email">Email da Pessoa de Contato</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" class="input-padrao" required placeholder="seuemail@dominio.com" name="email">

                <label for="telefone">Telefone da Pessoa de Contato</label>
                <input type="tel" id="telefone" class="input-padrao" required placeholder="(XX) XXXXX-XXXX" name="telefone">
```

...................................................

Php mailer

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])) {

$nome = addslashes($_POST['nomeempresa']);
$cnpj = addslashes($_POST['cnpjempresa']);
$contatoPessoa = addslashes($_POST['pessoacontato']);
$setor = addslashes($_POST['setorcontato']);
$estado = addslashes($_POST['estado']);
$cidade = addslashes($_POST['cidade']);
$cep = addslashes($_POST['cep']);
$email = addslashes($_POST['email']);
$telefone = addslashes($_POST['telefone']);
$contato = addslashes($_POST['contato']);
$preferencia = addslashes($_POST['preferenciaContato']);
$motivo = addslashes($_POST['motivoContato']);
$vidro = addslashes($_POST['reciclaveisvidro']);
$vidro1 = addslashes($_POST['produtoespecifico1']);
$borracha = addslashes($_POST['reciclaveisborracha']);
$borracha1 = addslashes($_POST['produtoespecifico2']);
$organico = addslashes($_POST['reciclaveisorganico']);
$organico1 = addslashes($_POST['produtoespecifico3']);
$reee = addslashes($_POST['reciclaveisreee']);
$reee1 = addslashes($_POST['produtoespecifico4']);
$quimico = addslashes($_POST['reciclaveisquimico']);
$quimico1 = addslashes($_POST['produtoespecifico5']);
$papel = addslashes($_POST['reciclaveispapel']);
$papel1 = addslashes($_POST['produtoespecifico6']);
$madeira = addslashes($_POST['reciclaveismadeira']);
$madeira1 = addslashes($_POST['produtoespecifico7']);
$tecido = addslashes($_POST['reciclaveistecido']);
$tecido1 = addslashes($_POST['produtoespecifico8']);
$plastico = addslashes($_POST['reciclaveisplastico']);
$plastico1 = addslashes($_POST['produtoespecifico9']);
$metais = addslashes($_POST['reciclaveismetais']);
$metais1 = addslashes($_POST['produtoespecifico10']);
$rcc = addslashes($_POST['reciclaveisrcc']);
$rcc1 = addslashes($_POST['produtoespecifico11']);
$sucata = addslashes($_POST['reciclaveissucata']);
$sucata1 = addslashes($_POST['produtoespecifico12']);
 
 $body = "Nome: ".$nome. "\r\n".
        "CNPJ: ".$cnpj. "\r\n".
        "Pessoa de Contato: ".$contatoPessoa. "\r\n".
        "Setor da Pessoa de Contato: ".$setor. "\r\n".
        "Estado: ".$estado. "\r\n".
        "Cidade: ".$cidade. "\r\n".
        "CEP: ".$cep. "\r\n".
        "E-mail: ".$email. "\r\n".
        "Telefone: ".$telefone. "\r\n".
        "Contato: ".$contato. "\r\n".
        "Prefernencia de Contato: ".$preferencia. "\r\n".
        "Motivo do Contato: ".$motivo;

$from = "teste@teste.com";
    
$to = "recebedor1@gmail.com, recebedor2@gmail.com";  

$subject = "Pedido cadastrado!";

$message = "Essa e uma mensagem de teste.";

$header = "From:teste@teste.com"."\r\n".

"Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n".

"X=Mailer:PHP/".phpversion();

 if(mail ($to,$subject,$body,$header)){
    echo ("E-mail enviado com sucesso");

 } else {
    echo ("E-mail não pode ser enviado");

}

}



?>
```

Vocês conseguiriam me ajudar?

Comment: Nicolas a sua pergunta tem muita coisa, eu recomendo você reduzir o código postado e preferencialmente simular uma versão abstrata do seu problema de maneira que possamos provar, isso provavelmente é um problema de debug, em algum lugar no seu código você está fazendo algo que não deveria e não é o nosso trabalho debugar o código por você.  Tente editar a sua pergunta para  maiores chances de se obter uma boa resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Tente mudar os id's desses campos que estão sendo carregados erroneamente, e realize o mapeamento novamente.

Se precisar debugar, utilize o print_r(array).